# The value of a checkbox is bound to a property of an object, but how can I catch a possible change by the user?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor Server app where I validate a list of objects after a property is changed across all objects (In this test case, for simplicity, one object with two properties).

At application startup, I generate a list of Ten objects and show them in a table.

Via an InputText field in an EditForm. the user should enter text. The TextChanged event iterates over the list and changes the property MyProperty for each object. As soon as the IsValid property returns true, the IsChecked property of the checkboxes is set.

I want to give the user the choice to deselect some objects. This also works by clicking, but I don't know how to query the user change.

Clicking on the submit button should only submit valid objects where the checkbox is also selected. How can I check / bind this?

The test object.

```
namespace CheckBoxTest.Data
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool IsValid => MyProperty.Length >= 4;

        // public bool IsSelected ... ?
    }
}
```

The Index.razor.

```
@using CheckBoxTest.Data
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model="_myObjects" OnValidSubmit="SaveMyObjectsAsync">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="myProperty">
            MyProperty
        </label>
        <InputText id="myProperty" @oninput="ChangeMyProperty" @bind-Value="_myProperty" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="(Please enter some text here...)" />
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <br />
        MyObjetsTable
        <br />

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 15px;"></th>
                    <th>MyProperty</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (MyObject myObject in _myObjects)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="@myObject.IsValid" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @myObject.MyProperty
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary oi oi-data-transfer-upload"/>
    </p>
</EditForm>

@code {

    private string _myProperty = string.Empty;

    private List<MyObject> _myObjects = new();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CreateMyObjects();
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void CreateMyObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _myObjects.Add(new MyObject());
        }
    }

    private async void ChangeMyProperty(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            foreach (MyObject myObject in _myObjects)
            {
                myObject.MyProperty = e.Value.ToString()!;
            }

            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    private async Task SaveMyObjectsAsync()
    {
        List<MyObject> _myObjectsToSave = new();

        foreach (MyObject myObject in _myObjects)
        {
            if (myObject.IsValid // && myObject.IsSelected ?)
            {
                _myObjectsToSave.Add(myObject);
            }
        }

        // await MySaveLogic.ExecuteAsync(_myObjectsToSave);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using something like this
`<input type="checkbox" checked="@myObject.IsValid" @onchange=" (e) => CheckboxChanged(e, myObject)">`

```
    private void CheckboxChanged(ChangeEventArgs e,MyObject obj)
    {
        obj.IsValid = e.Value;
    }
```